Why can't a non-stationary AR process be represented as an infinite MA process?
Consider the AR(1) process. If $|\phi|<1$, the process is stationary, and we can express the series as
$$ Y_t = \epsilon_t + \phi\epsilon_{t-1} + \phi^2\epsilon_{t-2} + \phi^3\epsilon_{t-3} + \cdots $$
I have heard that only a stationary AR process can be represented as an infinite MA process, so taking AR(1) as an example, why doesn't this hold if $|\phi| \geq 1$?

Hi: if you derive the expression, then it's clearer why.
We have : $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$.
Then, using the lag operator, we have:
$y_{t}(1 - \phi L) = \epsilon_{t}$.
But, if one tries to divide by $(1-\phi L)$ on both sides when $\phi \ge 1.0$, this does not lead to the past infinite sum of the $\epsilon_{t}$ because $\phi \ge 1.0$.  When $\phi \ge 1.0$, then $\frac{1}{1-\phi L}$ cannot be written as an infinite series in the past. ( well, you can but the series doesn't converge. )
As an aside, note that, when $\phi \ge 1$, then there is a way to write $\frac{1}{1-\phi L}$ as an infinite series in the future but, in that case, the AR(1) is not causal.
